# I called then() on a TypeScript promise but it is still pending. Why is this? How can I get it to resolve?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

Here is the index.ts script I am running (based on something I found on reddit):

```
const path = require("path");
const sql = require("mssql");
const config = require(path.resolve("./config.json"));

let db1;

const connect = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db1 = new sql.ConnectionPool(config.db, err => {
            if (err) {
                console.error("Connection failed.", err);
                reject(err);
            } else {
                console.log("Database pool #1 connected.");
                resolve();
            }
        });
    });
};

const selectProjects = async (name) => {
    const query = `
        select * from [Time].ProjectData where [Name] like concat('%', concat(@name, '%'))`;

    const request = new sql.Request(db1);
    const result = await request
        .input("name", name)
        .query(query);

    return result.recordset;
};

module.exports = {
    connect,
    selectProjects
};

connect().then(function() {
    console.log(selectProjects('General'));
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

When I run the script using `node index` (after compiling it of course), I get this in the console:

```
Database pool #1 connected.
Promise { <pending> }
```

And then the script hangs.

Comment: Its important to note that this is not a feature of typescript Promises, typescript doesn't change promises nor change any underlying functionality of javascript.

Answer (score -2):

Apparently the await keyword creates an implicit promise; I had to change the last function call to:

```
connect().then(function() {
    selectProjects('General').then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);      
    });
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: `await` does not create an implicit promise. You can call `await` on non async functions and it won't create a promise. Promises are created when you do `new Promise` or implicitly when you use the `async` keyword.

Comment: All async functions return a promise (by design).  Whatever you manually `return` from the function, it will become the resolved value of the promise that the async function returns.  So, when calling any async function, you have to either use `.then()` or `await` to get the actual returned value from it (which it appears you have realized).